# Haskell. Why is :info (:) returns the definition twice?

Tags: haskell, types, infix-notation

I'm new to haskell.

If I type in GHCi (7.10.3):

```
:info (:)
```

I get result:

```
*** Parser:
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :

data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

Does it means that operator is defined twice?
I didn't find any suspicious things in the source =/

Comment: The definition of `[]` is full of magic; I'd take anything GHCi says about it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I would call this a bug. Feel free to report it on the bug tracker.

Comment: Same issue with ghc 7.8.4.

Comment: @gallais can you provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay no attention to this, it's certainly a bug. I can reproduce this behavior on GHC 7.10.3, but the current GHC 8.0 development snapshot doesn't suffer from this issue:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.0.20160316: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :info (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

Comment: Another one bites the dust! I wonder what got it fixed--if it only caused this one peculiarity, I doubt anyone would've bothered. Perhaps the code was rewritten for some more substantial reason.